# Spaces disappear when holding mouse over table - Chrome issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need help trying to figure out why this happens. Can't seem to come up with a solution.

in JSFiddle the hovering works fine, but when opened in chrome without jsfiddle the boxes partially disappear if you hold your mouse on some boxes.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F8VNN/1/

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="main-table-header">File Name</th>
            <th class="main-table-header">File Size</th>
            <th class="main-table-header">Date Added</th>
            <th class="main-table-header"># Of Versions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<!-- Beginning of dll list. -->
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">DSWINSAT.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">10.KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">04/05/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">4 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">DxEngine32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1.03MB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">01/09/2012</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">No Other Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">litezip.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">21.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">06/08/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">4 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">rasapi32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">93.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">12/09/2014</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">3 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">ecomwr.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">21.1KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">10/10/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">2 Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">mfcuia32.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">43.9KB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">08/09/2001</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">No Other Versions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="new-dll-start">
            <td class="main-table-body">icuuc51.dll</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1.1MB</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">06/09/2013</td>
            <td class="main-table-body">1 Version</td>
        </tr>
<!-- End of dll list. -->
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="main-table-header2">File Name</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2">File Size</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2">Date Added</th>
            <th class="main-table-header2"># Of Versions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main-table-header{
color:#FFFFFF;
background:#000000;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
width: 200px;
}
.main-table-body{
text-align:center;
background:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
-moz-transition: all .2s;
-webkit-transition: all .2s;
transition: all .2s;
background-color: whitesmoke;
display:absolute;
padding: 2px;
}
.main-table-body:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
.main-table-header2{
color:#FFFFFF;
background:#000000;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
}
```

Comment: If it's not happening in the jsfiddle, it suggests that your page has something else in the code causing the issue. Do you have a link?

Comment: Yes http://dll-download.us/

Comment: You have to have enough code here to reproduce the problem, otherwise this question isn't much use to future visitors.

Comment: @cimmanon then what code are you looking for? This is the exact code linked with the exact css classes it uses.